# Ibm mq, sending messages to queue without specifying a user

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a spring app, and I've received information to connect to ibm mq. I've got everything except user and password. When I was using [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/mq/) I had a user and password (specified using `MQ_APP_PASSWORD` env. variable). It's obvious that I can connect to ibmmq queue with just a username, but the question is, if I can connect without both ? does ibmmq allow for something like this ?

Comment: It depends on how the MQ admin has setup the queue manager.  If they have provided channel and port but no user/password then they may have setup the connection to associate a specific user to the channel, if they did not provide any additional security with TLS certs then anyone that can access the IP and PORT and figure out the channel name can connect.

Comment: Setting up either MQ or your client application to not require a UserId and Password is a very bad idea.  Security is important and setting everything up from the beginning is the best solution unless you want to be responsible for bad actors (aka hackers) dumping data from your company.

Comment: "(...) but no user/password then they may have setup the connection to associate a specific user to the channel (...)" so is it theoretically possible to configure manager to let connect to it without giving a user ?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The MQ Advanced for Developers container images come with a [default configuration](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/blob/master/incubating/mqadvanced-server-dev/10-dev.mqsc.tpl) which enables security.  In this configuration, applications connect using the `DEV.APP.SVRCONN` channel.  I think that you should take a look at the `CHCKCLNT` attribute in [CONNAUTH](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.amqp.doc/amqp_security.htm).  In the default configuration, the `CHCKCLNT` attribute on the channel (CHLAUTH) is set to `REQUIRED` if you've set a password on the container (by setting the `MQ_APP_PASSWORD` environment variable), or set to `ASQMGR` otherwise.  The queue manager setting which this will fall back to, is set using CONNAUTH, on the `AUTHINFO` object, which is set to `REQDADM` by default.  So, not sending a user ID and password should already work.  However, if not, try adjusting the `AUTHINFO` object's `CHCKCLNT` setting.  Note that this could also have a knock-on effect on the `DEV.ADMIN.SVRCONN` channel, which also uses this default.

You can change the MQ configuration used in a Docker image by adding an MQSC as described [here](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container/blob/master/docs/usage.md).  You will need to refresh security at the end of your MQSC.